# Is it possible to write the value of a variable in a %%writefile magic command in IPython notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to use a variable to output some text in IPython Notebook. I can write to a file from within IPython Notebook using the %%writefile command. I can also use a variable to name the file using $varaible_name.

```
file_name = "file.out"
some_variable = "text"
```

New cell

```
%%writefile $file_name
????some_varaible  #<-what command goes here
```

So that the output file (named "file.out") looks like this:

text

Comment: Asking on github and SO at the same time is considered bad habit, wait at least a few hours, otherwise people will get annoyed when they see your message twice. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6701

Answer (score 5):

Now this is possible using the following command::

```
%store varname >filename.txt
```

[More about %store](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/storemagic.html)

Comment: What if this is an xml configuration file for example!

Comment: Note: I had to remove the space before "filename.txt" for this to work!

Comment: It should be `>filename.txt` or `>>filename.txt` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6701) github thread it is possible, but with custom magic command:

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_cell_magic

@register_line_cell_magic
def writetemplate(line, cell):
    with open(line, 'w') as f:
        f.write(cell.format(**globals()))
```

Usage:

```
some_variable = "text"
%%writetemplate filename.txt
test: {some_variable}
```